# Dart - How do I get the character that appears after 'code='?

Tags: dart

I need your help to code the way to get the value that comes after 'code=' in these 3 examples.

var url='https://example.com.ar/buy?code=76''

var url2='https://example.com.ar/buy?v=1.1.1&code=100&box=4''

var url3='https://www.example.com/api/compra?box=1&code=1&id=60'.

I tried this option but it only works for one of the options

```
main() {
final String url='https://www.example.com/api/compra?box=1&code=76&id=60';
final int startIndex=url.indexOf('code=',0)+5;
final int endIndex=url.length;
final String substring=url.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
print (substring);
}
```

I look forward to your comments. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
  final url='https://www.example.com/api/compra?box=1&code=76&id=60';
  final code = Uri.parse(url).queryParameters['code'];
```